# JS - insertBefore() infinite loop with getElementsByTagName

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a clone of `thead` without `tbody`. And wrap both tables within a `div`. Here is my sample code.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var table = document.getElementsByTagName('table');
  for (i = 0; i < table.length; i++) {

    function init() {
      var wrapper = document.createElement('div');
      wrapper.setAttribute('class', 'container');
      table[i].parentNode.insertBefore(wrapper, table[i]);
      wrapper.appendChild(table[i]); //works fine till now

      var t_fixed = table[i].cloneNode(true);
      t_fixed.classList.add('fixed');
      t_fixed.removeChild(t_fixed.tBodies[0]);
      table[i].parentNode.insertBefore(t_fixed, table[i]);
      console.log(i);
      console.log(t_fixed);
    }
    init();
  };
});
```

```html
<table class="purple">
  <thead>
    <th>Colored Text</th>
    <th>Color Preview</th>
    <th>Color Name</th>
    <th>Hex Value</th>
    <th>RGB Value</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Fuscia</td>
      <td>#f1a4b1</td>
      <td>102, 74, 51</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Print</td>
      <td>#ea12fb</td>
      <td>41, 45, 21</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Pink</td>
      <td>#aa12fa</td>
      <td>55, 84, 100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Gold</td>
      <td>#abcdef</td>
      <td>120, 210, 43</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table class="blue">
  <thead>
    <th>Colored Text</th>
    <th>Color Preview</th>
    <th>Color Name</th>
    <th>Hex Value</th>
    <th>RGB Value</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Fuscia</td>
      <td>#f1a4b1</td>
      <td>102, 74, 51</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Print</td>
      <td>#ea12fb</td>
      <td>41, 45, 21</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Pink</td>
      <td>#aa12fa</td>
      <td>55, 84, 100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Gold</td>
      <td>#abcdef</td>
      <td>120, 210, 43</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

How can I limit this loop to each table for once.

Comment: you're cloning the thead and then ?

Comment: You might consider moving the function `init` definition out of the loop and instead pass the table and other values it needs as function arguments. Currently, you are redefining the function on every loop iteration which is unnecessary.

Comment: @Boudyhesham adding a class `fixed` and removing the tbody. Only keeping the `thead`. and placing it before original html table.

Comment: @AbrarHossain i am planning to add more functions in this loop. That's why I am placing function `init` definition inside loop.

Comment: @abjim I understand but you will be better off in moving the declaration outside. You can pass the reference to table, wrapper and other data like this: `init(table, wrapper, ...otherArgs)`.

Comment: @abjim have you look at my answer?

Comment: @Boudyhesham yes bro I saw your answer. But It only adds the thead to my dom. Not my previous table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start by your mistakes you were trying to make the function defenition inside the loop and that's a wrong declaration you could call the function and make the for loop inside the function. or you can make it anonymous function. Second you had infinite loop there.
**EDIT**
look at this snippet

```js
var table = document.getElementsByTagName("table");
table = [].slice.call(table);

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
  for (i = 0; i < table.length; i++) {
    var wrapper = document.createElement("div"),
      clone = table[i].cloneNode(true),
      parent = table[i].parentNode;
    clone.classList.add("fixed");
    wrapper.classList.add("container");
    for (let j = 0; j < clone.tBodies.length; j++) {
      clone.removeChild(clone.tBodies[j]);
    }
    wrapper.appendChild(clone);
    parent.insertBefore(wrapper, table[i]);
    wrapper.appendChild(table[i]);
  }
});
```

```html
 <table class="purple">
      <thead>
        <th>Colored Text</th>
        <th>Color Preview</th>
        <th>Color Name</th>
        <th>Hex Value</th>
        <th>RGB Value</th>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td>Fuscia</td>
          <td>#f1a4b1</td>
          <td>102, 74, 51</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td>Print</td>
          <td>#ea12fb</td>
          <td>41, 45, 21</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td>Pink</td>
          <td>#aa12fa</td>
          <td>55, 84, 100</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td>Gold</td>
          <td>#abcdef</td>
          <td>120, 210, 43</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

    <table class="blue">
      <thead>
        <th>Colored Text</th>
        <th>Color Preview</th>
        <th>Color Name</th>
        <th>Hex Value</th>
        <th>RGB Value</th>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td>Fuscia</td>
          <td>#f1a4b1</td>
          <td>102, 74, 51</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td>Print</td>
          <td>#ea12fb</td>
          <td>41, 45, 21</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td>Pink</td>
          <td>#aa12fa</td>
          <td>55, 84, 100</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td>Gold</td>
          <td>#abcdef</td>
          <td>120, 210, 43</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

i will start by explaining the code, first we're selecting the tables and it returns a **live collection** .
then we're creating the div, cloning the thead of the table adding the fixed class to it then appending the clone to the new element inserting the div to the dom by insertbefore as you wanted, last we're removing the old table and decreasing the index because we've live htmlCollection.

Comment: It only appends new table with  only thead and removes my previous table. I want dom tree like this [image](https://imgur.com/Uy9qT8p)

Comment: @abjim cool the structure looks like your img hope this helps.

Comment: whoaa here it looks cool really. I thought a lot, but couldn't found any final solution. But your answer made it possible. I am trying to make a scrollable page with vanilla js. without using any kind of plugins/libraries. The final version would be like this [scrollable table using jQuery](https://jsfiddle.net/8pqdwbru/)

Comment: @abjim well the problem that live htmlCollection keeps track of the dom so whenever you select using by tagname or children try converting them to arrays, they act as array-like object keep eye on that, if this is the correct answer please accept it.

Comment: @abjim thx, and i've a suggestion, if you're trying to achieve something like this link u posted https://jsfiddle.net/8pqdwbru/ what about css position sticky?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224556/discussion-between-abjim-and-boudy-hesham).